# 1 x AA sized battery box with a built in switch?

Tags: batteries, switches

I have been looking around all the internet for such a thing, but I haven't found one. Do they exist? All I would need is a neat little plastic battery holder for 1 AA sized battery, which has a switch included. Just like it's common with 2x, 3x, 4x AA sized boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start looking [here on Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/search/refine.aspx?Ntk=P_MarCom&Ntt=106652559&utm_source=supplier&utm_medium=featured+spotlight&utm_campaign=106652559).  I've got a number of enclosed battery holders with switches and wire leads.  I don't have any single-cell holders, but several 2- and 3-cell ones.  It's a place to start, at least…

Answer (score 1):

Use a 2xAA box rewired for a single cell.